# Separate dataobject variables for controls using MVVM design pattern

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, .net-4.6

Let us say we have a data object which contains two values *CompanyID* and *Price*. Also I have more than one control which depending on *CompanyID* should update *Price*.

There are four grids with same layout each layout contains a `<TextBlock/>` control in it. All controls share same variable (*Price*). If I put `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Price}"/>` in each of four layouts same value will be updated on every single control. It should update only one `<TextBlock/>` depending on *CompanyID* given. Prices will be updated at the runtime.

In modelView constructor:

```
PriceObj = new Model(CompanyID, Price);
```

Object will be stored in a property (PriceObj) which is owned by modelView.

What would be the best practice to distinguish which control should update *Price* value regarding *CompanyID* value?

Would it be better to create a different *Price* for each company, let us say *Price0*, *Price1* and then accessing those values directly via DataBinding in XAML?

Can distinguish be made within `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface implementation?

Note: I do not want the easiest way, I want most MVVM pattern suited way. Code example would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'd avoid "best" in title, because this assumes opinion-based answers and will lead question to closing.

Comment: Noted. I have edited. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have 100 companies, and each company has its own price, it's very inefficient to produce `Price0`...`Price99` properties. This is not about MVVM, this is about common sense.

Obviously, the way to go is a collection of `PriceObj` at View Model level, and `ItemsControl` at View level. Something like this:

```
public PriceObj
{
    public int CompanyID { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}

public class PriceEditorViewModel
{
     public ObservableCollection<PriceObj> Prices { ... }
     /* ... */
}
```

XAML:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Prices}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding CompanyID}"/>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Price}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

`ItemsControl` (`ListBox` in sample) generates a separate set of controls per item in `ItemsSource`. In the markup above controls are defined using `DataTemplate` (more about data templating [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms742521%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How do you separate which price goes to which control within XAML then? As it does not have to change other control values.

Comment: @Carll think of a foreach loop which gives listitem0 price0 and listitem1 price1 and so on

Comment: @Carl: updated the answer. `ItemsControl` does this for you.

Comment: Foreach loop code would only be usable in c#. There should not be any txtbox1.Text = value; within the code behind, that should be done in XAML via binding, thus this will not work in my case. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Dennis There are more than one <TextBox/>. All share same parameter of Price, only one of the TextBox has to update value its value at the time depending on CompanyID.

Comment: @Carl: it doesn't matter, how complex visual tree is. Since I don't know, how exactly your classes look like, I can't understand, what is "same parameter of Price". If you'll change `TextBox` text, it will update appropriate `PriceObj`. May be, if you'll share more details, the question will become more clear.

Comment: Ok. Let me try to explain. I will edit question accordingly. There is exactly four grinds each own three controls (TextBlock). I get data which consist of two parameters ComanyID and Price. All Four Grids has same layout. If I put <TextBlock Text="{Binding Price}"/> in each of four layouts all four TextBlock controls will updated accordingly. I want only one of four TextBlock to update depending on which company is selected. Hope that makes it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question fully but I guess you have list of companies and their price and you want to show the price when someone selects a company?
If it's the case, I'd create 2 grids, one for the companies, and other for the prices.
I'd also create lists of companies and prices in the view model and whenever someone selects a company, I'd filter price list in view model.

May be I dint understand your qq.

Comment: GUI is static and structure cannot be changed. It has to change one of the controls value depending on which company's value.